# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: engineListeners

Tags: java, speech-recognition

I am writing a speech recognition program and i have come across this error.

Things I have tried:

Debug and rerun the program

Checked to see if there is any repeating jars in libraries

I am really confused? Can anyone help?
By the way the full error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: engineListeners
>     at
>   com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRecognizer.fireRecognizerSuspended(BaseRecognizer.java:977)
>     at
>   com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRecognizer.dispatchSpeechEvent(BaseRecognizer.java:1273)
>     at
>   com.sun.speech.engine.SpeechEventUtilities.postSpeechEvent(SpeechEventUtilities.java:201)
>     at
>   com.sun.speech.engine.SpeechEventUtilities.postSpeechEvent(SpeechEventUtilities.java:132)
>     at
>   com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRecognizer.postRecognizerSuspended(BaseRecognizer.java:965)
>     at
>   com.sun.speech.engine.recognition.BaseRecognizer.commitChanges(BaseRecognizer.java:375)
>     at
>   edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi.JSGFGrammar.createGrammar(JSGFGrammar.java:288)
>     at
>   edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.language.grammar.Grammar.allocate(Grammar.java:123)
>     at
>   edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.allocate(FlatLinguist.java:225)
>     at
>   edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.allocate(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:576)
>     at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.allocate(Decoder.java:109)    at
>   edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.allocate(Recognizer.java:182)    at
>   demo.sphinx.speech.Program.main(Program.java:71)

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        URL url;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            url = new File(args[0]).toURI().toURL();
        } else {
            url = Program.class.getResource("SpeechConfig.config.xml");
        }

        System.out.println("Loading...");

        ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(url);

        Recognizer recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");

        Microphone microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");
        recognizer.allocate();

        if (microphone.startRecording()) {

            System.out.println
            ("Listening");

            while (true) {

                Result result = recognizer.recognize();

                if (result != null) {
                    resultText = result.getBestFinalResultNoFiller();

                } else {
                    System.out.println("I can't hear what you said.\n");
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Cannot start microphone.");
            recognizer.deallocate();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem when loading Program: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PropertyException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem configuring Program: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        System.err.println("Problem creating Program: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: You should not use this code at all. Recent sphinx4 tutorial is here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Comment: Thank you, but is what does the error mean, by "engineListeners"?

Comment: It is a bug caused by version incompatibility of the jars you are trying to use.